# Call to undefined function each() in php 8.1

Tags: php, each

I've never got this error before but now since I am running php 8.1 then this piece of code is obsolete.

```
// addslashes to vars if magic_quotes_gpc is off
// this is a security precaution to prevent someone
// trying to break out of a SQL statement.
//
//if( !@get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);{
    if( is_array($HTTP_GET_VARS) )
    {
        while( list($k, $v) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS) )
        {
            if( is_array($HTTP_GET_VARS[$k]) )
            {
                while( list($k2, $v2) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS[$k]) )
                {
                    $HTTP_GET_VARS[$k][$k2] = addslashes($v2);
                }
                @reset($HTTP_GET_VARS[$k]);
            }
            else
            {
                $HTTP_GET_VARS[$k] = addslashes($v);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php The function was removed.

Comment: PLease dont put the error message in the title

Comment: Nothing mentioning magic quotes should really be in production anymore. `In November 2005 the core PHP developers decided that because of these problems, the magic quotes feature would be removed from PHP 6`. So 17 years ago that feature was planned to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each()` function has been removed as of PHP 8.0.
I would recommend replacing the each function with the `foreach` syntax.

```
foreach ($HTTP_GET_VARS as $k => $v) {
  $kv = [$k, $v];
}
```

Comment: Really only deserves a comment and then closing the quesiton. Questions like this are no use to others

Comment: @RiggsFolly, too bad this is the very first result that appears in google when you search for called to undefined function each and it has to do with being deprecated.